# How to cache a query for each user for 24 hours?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, memcached

Caching seems very complicated to me. There are too many ways to cache and I am certainly not able to follow any of them. In my app, for each user, on his profile I am displaying 24 random users:

```
@random_users = User.random(24)
```

Now I want to cache the result for each user for 24 hours. So User A signs in and the query is run just once in 24 hours. Then User B signs in and same thing happens. However, I want the cache results for each user to be stored separately. Meaning, if User B signs in after User A, I don't want User A's cache to expire. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work, you must use a different cache key for each user so that this information is kept separately for each user. For example you could do

```
@random_users = Rails.cache.fetch "random_uses_for_user_#{current_user.id}", :expire_in => 24.hours do
  ...
end
```

assuming `current_user` is the user for whom you are fetching this information.

Comment: This doesn't work.. In my controller, I have:           `Rails.cache.fetch "randoms_for_user_#{current_user.id}", :expires_in => 24.hours do
            @random_users = User.random(24)
          end` It makes a query for the first time and displays 24 random users, but on subsequent page views or if I refresh the page NO RANDOM USERS ARE DISPLAYED.

Comment: On subsequent loads that block isn't executed at all, so you shouldn't have any side effects in there. Move the assignment to outside the block